# Difference between ! and ~

Tags: c, logical-operators

I was implementing a simple state machine as follows:

```
typedef void V_V_StateFunc(void);
static V_V_StateFunc *const fpCurrentStateFunc[STATE_ELEM_SIZE]={

    &fn1,/*0*/

};

void Execute_StateMachine(const U8 bCurrent_StateIndex)
{
    if(bStateIndex == (~bInvert_StateIndex))
    {
        if(bCurrent_StateIndex <= STATE_ELEM_SIZE)
        {
            fpCurrentStateFunc[bCurrent_StateIndex]();
        }
        else
        {
            /*this should never enter*/
        }   
    }
    else
    {
            /*this should never enter*/
    }
}

void Update_State(U8 bNewIndex)
{
    bStateIndex=bNewIndex; //bStateIndex & bInvert_StateIndex are globals
    bInvert_StateIndex=(~bNewIndex);
}
```

In the function `Execute_StateMachine()`, if I check `bStateIndex == (~bInvert_StateIndex)`, the value is always 0 and nevers enter the if statement, though `bStateIndex=0` and `~bInvert_StateIndex=0` (i.e `0 == 0`, which is true). 
Why is this happening?

If I change `bStateIndex == (!bInvert_StateIndex)`,it enters the `if` statement.

What is the difference between `~` and `!` here?

Comment: i tried adding V_V_StateFunc const * const , but Keil is not allowing me to do that. It says "StateJumpTables.c(8): warning:  #925-D: type qualifiers on function types are ignored.static V_V_StateFunc const *const fpCurrentStateFunc[STATE_ELEM_SIZE]={"

Comment: Any idea as to why Keil is doing that?

Comment: Because functions are `const` by default, kind of. It doesn't make sense to modify a function programmatically. That being said writing `V_V_StateFunc const*const` is not wrong, just superfluous.

Comment: yes. Thats wat i thought too. Just wanted to make sure that there was no technical reason as to y Keil was warning me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess it happens because of integer promotion. The `~` operator is a dangerous one to use, since its operand is integer promoted. So the promoted operand is of type `int` here and not `U8` as you might think.

Meaning that if you pass the value 0xFF to `~`, the result will be not be 0x00 as you might expect, but 0xFFFFFF00. Temporarily stored in a signed `int`.

Avoid this by *always* casting the result of the `~` operator to the intended type:

```
bStateIndex == (U8)(~bInvert_StateIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about Integer promotion. can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @SKD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094412/what-is-the-difference-between-integral-promotion-and-balancing-in-c/12137502#12137502

Comment: By using "bStateIndex == (U8)(~bInvert_StateIndex)", it enters the if statement.

Comment: I intend on keeping the ~ approach and not the ! approach because i want to ensure that each bit is flipped based on Index and not just a logical operation for each index. I want to use this to check that any corruption in the RAM location for bStateIndex should be identified before calling the function. Il of-course typecast it to U8 before comparison

Comment: @Vector9 I would recommend that you take a look at using the MISRA-C coding standard. It would have prevented this bug and many others.

Comment: Yes i am doing it parallely using PC-Lint. I hadnt checked this in Lint yet. Was gonna check

Answer (score 8):

the `!` operator is the **logical not** operator; for example the expression

```
if (!variable)
```

is equal to:

```
if (variable == 0)
```

The `~` operator is the **bitwise NOT** operator; thus changing the value of each bit.

```
 char variable = 1;           // value: 00000001
 char variable2 = ~variable;  // value: 11111110 = 254  (as noted by @Lundin; value = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 and then truncated to 11111110 upon assignment to char)
```

Comment: Rather, value: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 and then truncated to 11111110 upon assignment to char.

Answer (score 2):

`!` will change any value that is not zero to zero, and will change zero to one.

`~` will perform a bitwise complement, switching every individual bit in the value between 0 and 1, but many of the possible values that are not zero will still not be zero after this operation.  This means that `x` and `~x` can both test as true (but they can't both test as false).

Also, because integer promotion occurs before the complement, it's impossible for any unsigned 8-bit integer to compare equal to the bitwise complement of another unsigned 8-bit integer, because the result of the complement is larger than will fit in an 8-bit type.

Comment: The integer promotion occurs before the operand of `~` is changed, it has nothing to do with the comparison in this case.

Comment: Detail: "! will change any value that is not zero to zero" is well said as `! double_with_not_a_number_value` returns `0`.

Comment: @Lundin, well, before them both... but yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: @chux That was dumb luck.  I almost never think about floats, let alone NaN.

Answer (score 1):

! is logical.

~ is bitwise.

chris

Answer (score 0):

! treat the value as boolean

if its 0 it will be 1

if its (anything but not 0) it will be 0

~ treat the value of each bit (do a 2's complement)

if its 7 (111b) it will be -8  (the extra -1 for 2's complement)

Answer (score 0):

**! (Logical NOT operator)** : It returns either true of false of an operation.The operation return type is always a boolean type.If the operation returns true, ! operator converts it to false and viceversa.
**(eg) : !(1==2) returns TRUE whereas normally (1==2) returns false.**

**~ (Bitwise Unary Complement Operator)** : This Unary operator works on binary values(0's and 1's) of the operand given.It processes the binary values and returns the output in operand's original type.
**(eg): ~(2) processes complement on the binary value of  2 (0010) and performs 2's complement operation on (0010) and returns the output in operand's original return type,(ie) the final output is -3.**

Comment: The actual answer to my question is : Integer promotion causes a failure. Also in ur example, if 2 is stored as unsigned type, the answer wont be -3 but 13(if typecasted to appropriate size).The output depends on whether its signed or unsigned

Comment: ok . yes the output varies depending whether it is signed or unsigned.